# Javascript вывод html кода

Tags: javascript, php, html

у меня есть небольшой чат, раньше я выводил с него сообщения по средствам php, то есть использовал echo. Но сейчас я решил динамически обновлять данные на страницы без перезагрузки, благодаря ajax, JS. Подскажите как теперь выводить код html, только на js. InnerHtml не подходит (Либо я не понимаю как его использовать), поскольку надо выводить целые div блоки. Да ещё и разные в зависимости от условия.

Старый код на php, который надо заменить:

```js
        function mparser($col){ // Создаем функцию чтобы иметь возможность вызывать ещё когда загружаем ещё сообщения
            

            $login = $_SESSION['logged_user']->login;
            $var = R::findOne('users', 'WHERE `login`=?', [$login]);
            $cou = R::count('messages');        // Сколько записей (элементов) в таблице book
            $colm = R::count('messages'); // количество сообщений
            global $colm;
            if ($var->show >= $colm){
                $col = $colm - 1;
            }
                                                // Выводим все сообщения через цикл 
                for ($i = $cou - $col; $i < $cou + 1; $i++) {
                    $message = R::findOne('messages', 'WHERE `idm`=?', [$i]);   // Парсим сообщение по его id через счетчик цикла
                    if ($message->login == $var->login){      // Если сообщение от нас отображаем справа    
                        echo('<div class="mess" id="me1">
                            <div class="message" id="me">
                                <img src="'. $message->ava .'">
                                <span id="ff">'. $message->text .'</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>');
                    }else{     // Если это сообщение не от нас 
                        $message = R::findOne('messages', 'WHERE `idm`=?', [$i + 1]); // Достаем следующее сообщение

                        $nextlogin = $message->login;
                        $nexttext = $message->text;

                        $message = R::findOne('messages', 'WHERE `idm`=?', [$i]); // Возвращаем обратно 

                        if ($message->login == $nextlogin and empty($nexttext) == FALSE){ // Отображение логина 
                            echo('<div class="mess">
                            <div class="message">
                                <img src="'. $message->ava .'">
                                <span>'. $message->text .'</span>
                            </div>
                            </div>');
                        }else{
                            echo('<div class="mess">
                            <div class="message">
                                <img src="'. $message->ava .'">
                                <span>'. $message->text .'</span>
                                <text>'. $message->login.'</text>
                            </div>
                            </div>');
                        }
                    }
                }   
        }
```

Новый зачаток кода:

```js
function parser(countMessages, ArrayMessage){
                for (var i = 0; i < NumberShowMessage; i++) { // Здесь уже начинаем с 0, так как разбираем массив
                    
                    // Разбираем массив 
                    let text = ArrayMessage[i][0];  
                    let login = ArrayMessage[i][1];   
                    let ava = ArrayMessage[i][2]; 

                    alert(text,login,ava);

                    if (login == OurLogin){                   // Если сообщение от нас отображаем справа

                        document.write('<div class="mess" id="me1">
                            <div class="message" id="me">
                                <img src="">
                                <span id="ff"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>');
    

                    //document.write(); // Выводим в html сообщения
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перебрав большое количество вариантов, остановился на `jQuery(element).append(your html);`

- `document.write` - работает только до загрузки страницы
- `document.html` - удаляет другой HTML на странице, поэтому в моём случае мне подошёл `append()`

P.S Спасибо @КириллуПанишеву, он натолкнул на решение.

Comment: Не думаю, что  Кирилл проникнется вам душой за слова благодарности, заработал чей-то минус и лишился "галочки" помогая вам.  @КириллПанишев Вам надо править ответ, а писать комментарии. Комментарии служат для уточнений, они __не являются составной частью ответа__.

Answer (score 0):

Тут наверное проще всего подключить jQuery и использовать метод `.html()`

Comment: JQuery подключен, сейчас попробую если сработает, то это отличный совет

Comment: Например вот так, https://codepen.io/shelder14/pen/OJgWLpo возможно из-за отступов или ковычек ошибка, пишите в одну строчку html

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Я уточнил, что было непонятно автору в комментариях и даже применил этот метод на его конкретно примере. Не понимаю как ещё более полно ему ответить. Тем более все равно он уже сюда не вернется.

Comment: Вернулся, в целом спасибо, но для моих задач я комбинировал его с document.innerHtml, проблема ещё в том что после .html() удаляется весь следующий код, разбираюсь с этим

Comment: В общем и целом, сейчас я использую document.write(), но html код записываю в одну строку. Хотя тот вариант тоже работает, этот мне симпатизирует больше. В любом случае спасибо